# problem File not found

Tags: warnings

In my work on TexMaker I get the error file not found while:
1- PdfLaTex is the line

```
-syncte=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
```

2-  I make that sure, program files in good condition by running another small testing, there was no

warning

3- could you please check my script

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{french}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
%\usepackage{lmodern}
%\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usetheme{Antibes}
%\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usecolortheme{crane}
%\usetheme{Berkeley}
%\usepackage{textpos}
%\usecolortheme{wolverine}
%\usetheme{Boadilla}

\definecolor{asparagus}{rgb}{0.53, 0.66, 0.42}
\usecolortheme[named=asparagus]{structure}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}
\title{\textbf {Theoretical Study of Electrical Conductivity in Graphene-Like Materials}}
\author{Latifah Salem Alrobiei \texorpdfstring{ \\ [1cm]{\small Supervised by \\ Dr.Narjes A. Ben Brabim \hspace{35pt} Dr. Abdullah A. Shaltout} \\ {\small Assistant Prof. of Solid state \qquad Associate Prof. of Atomic and} \\ {physics \hfill \hspace{35pt} \qquad Molecular Spectra}}{}}


\institute[Taif University] % (optional, but mostly needed)
{
  \inst{1}%
  Department of Physics \\
  Taif University 
  }

\date{1442-2020}

\pgfdeclareimage[height=1.5cm]{university-logo}{TU}
\logo{\pgfuseimage{university-logo}}
\pgfdeclareimage[height=1.5cm]{university-logo}{TU}
\logo{\pgfuseimage{university-logo}}

\begin{document}


%@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}
%@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@


\end{document}
```

Thank you
the LOG FILE
part 1

```
LOG FILE :
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (MiKTeX 2.9.7000 64-bit) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2019.4.12) 23 AUG 2020 16:57
entering extended mode
**./introthesis.tex
(introthesis.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>
("C:\Users\Win8\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/beamer\beamer.cls"
Document Class: beamer 2018/12/02 v3.55 A class for typesetting presentations
("C:\Users\Win8\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/beamer\beamerbasemo
des.sty"
("C:\Users\Win8\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/etoolbox\etoolbox.s
ty"
Package: etoolbox 2018/08/19 v2.5f e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
\etb@tempcnta=\count80
)
\beamer@tempbox=\box27
\beamer@tempcount=\count81
\c@beamerpauses=\count82
("C:\Users\Win8\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/beamer\beamerbasede
code.sty"
\beamer@slideinframe=\count83
\beamer@minimum=\count84
)
\beamer@commentbox=\box28
\beamer@modecount=\count85
)
("C:\Users\Win8\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/oberdiek\ifpdf.st
y"
Package: ifpdf 2018/09/07 v3.3 Provides the ifpdf switch
)
\headdp=\dimen102
\footheight=\dimen103
\sidebarheight=\dimen104
\beamer@tempdim=\dimen105
\beamer@finalheight=\dimen106
\beamer@animht=\dimen107
\beamer@animdp=\dimen108
\beamer@animwd=\dimen109
\beamer@leftmargin=\dimen110
\beamer@rightmargin=\dimen111
\beamer@leftsidebar=\dimen112
\beamer@rightsidebar=\dimen113
\beamer@boxsize=\dimen114
\beamer@vboxoffset=\dimen115
\beamer@descdefault=\dimen116
\beamer@descriptionwidth=\dimen117
\beamer@lastskip=\skip41
\beamer@areabox=\box29
\beamer@animcurrent=\box30
\beamer@animshowbox=\box31
\beamer@sectionbox=\box32
\beamer@logobox=\box33
\beamer@linebox=\box34
\beamer@sectioncount=\count86
\beamer@subsubsectionmax=\count87
\beamer@subsectionmax=\count88
\beamer@sectionmax=\count89
\beamer@totalheads=\count90
\beamer@headcounter=\count91
\beamer@partstartpage=\count92
\beamer@sectionstartpage=\count93
\beamer@subsectionstartpage=\count94
\beamer@animationtempa=\count95
\beamer@animationtempb=\count96
\beamer@xpos=\count97
\beamer@ypos=\count98
\beamer@ypos@offset=\count99
\beamer@showpartnumber=\count100
\beamer@currentsubsection=\count101
\beamer@coveringdepth=\count102
\beamer@sectionadjust=\count103
\beamer@tocsectionnumber=\count104
("C:\Users\Win8\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/beamer\beamerbaseop
tions.sty"
("C:\Users\Win8\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics\keyval.sty
"
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks14
))
\beamer@paperwidth=\skip42
\beamer@paperheight=\skip43
("C:\Users\Win8\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/geometry\geometry.s
ty"
Package: geometry 2018/04/16 v5.8 Page Geometry
("C:\Users\Win8\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/oberdiek\ifvtex.s
ty"
Package: ifvtex 2016/05/16 v1.6 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
Package ifvtex Info: VTeX not detected.
)
("C:\Users\Win8\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/ifxetex\ifxetex.s
ty"
Package: ifxetex 2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
)
\Gm@cnth=\count105
\Gm@cntv=\count106
\c@Gm@tempcnt=\count107
\Gm@bindingoffset=\dimen118
\Gm@wd@mp=\dimen119
\Gm@odd@mp=\dimen120
\Gm@even@mp=\dimen121
\Gm@layoutwidth=\dimen122
\Gm@layoutheight=\dimen123
\Gm@layouthoffset=\dimen124
\Gm@layoutvoffset=\dimen125
\Gm@dimlist=\toks15
("C:\Users\Win8\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/geometry\geometry.c
fg"))
("C:\Users\Win8\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\size11.clo"
File: size11.clo 2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
("C:\Users\Win8\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer\pgfc
ore.sty"
("C:\Users\Win8\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics\graphicx.s
ty"
Package: graphicx 2017/06/01 v1.1a Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
("C:\Users\Win8\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics\graphics.s
ty"
Package: graphics 2017/06/25 v1.2c Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
("C:\Users\Win8\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics\trig.sty"
Package: trig 2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
("C:\Users\Win8\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics-cfg\graphi
cs.cfg"
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 99.
("C:\Users\Win8\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics-def\pdftex
.def"
File: pdftex.def 2018/01/08 v1.0l Graphics/color driver for pdftex
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen126
\Gin@req@width=\dimen127
)
("C:\Users\Win8\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/pgf/systemlayer\pgf
sys.sty"
("C:\Users\Win8\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/pgf/utilities\pgfrc
s.sty"
("C:\Users\Win8\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgf
util-common.tex"
\pgfutil@everybye=\toks16
\pgfutil@tempdima=\dimen128
\pgfutil@tempdimb=\dimen129
("C:\Users\Win8\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgf
util-common-lists.tex"))
("C:\Users\Win8\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgf
util-latex.def"
\pgfutil@abb=\box35
("C:\Users\Win8\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/ms\everyshi.sty"
Package: everyshi 2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
))
("C:\Users\Win8\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgf
rcs.code.tex"
("C:\Users\Win8\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf\pgf.revision.
tex")
Package: pgfrcs 2019/04/04 v3.1.2 (3.1.2)
))
("C:\Users\Win8\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer\p
gfsys.code.tex"
Package: pgfsys 2019/04/04 v3.1.2 (3.1.2)
("C:\Users\Win8\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgf
keys.code.tex"
\pgfkeys@pathtoks=\toks17
\pgfkeys@temptoks=\toks18
("C:\Users\Win8\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgf
keysfiltered.code.tex"
\pgfkeys@tmptoks=\toks19
))
\pgf@x=\dimen130
\pgf@y=\dimen131
\pgf@xa=\dimen132
\pgf@ya=\dimen133
\pgf@xb=\dimen134
\pgf@yb=\dimen135
\pgf@xc=\dimen136
\pgf@yc=\dimen137
\w@pgf@writea=\write3
\r@pgf@reada=\read1
\c@pgf@counta=\count108
\c@pgf@countb=\count109
\c@pgf@countc=\count110
\c@pgf@countd=\count111
\t@pgf@toka=\toks20
\t@pgf@tokb=\toks21
\t@pgf@tokc=\toks22
\pgf@sys@id@count=\count112
("C:\Users\Win8\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer\p
gf.cfg"
File: pgf.cfg 2019/04/04 v3.1.2 (3.1.2)
)
Driver file for pgf: pgfsys-pdftex.def
("C:\Users\Win8\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer\p
gfsys-pdftex.def"
File: pgfsys-pdftex.def 2019/04/04 v3.1.2 (3.1.2)
("C:\Users\Win8\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer\p
gfsys-common-pdf.def"
File: pgfsys-common-pdf.def 2019/04/04 v3.1.2 (3.1.2)
)))
("C:\Users\Win8\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer\p
gfsyssoftpath.code.tex"
File: pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex 2019/04/04 v3.1.2 (3.1.2)
\pgfsyssoftpath@smallbuffer@items=\count113
\pgfsyssoftpath@bigbuffer@items=\count114
)
("C:\Users\Win8\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer\p
gfsysprotocol.code.tex"
File: pgfsysprotocol.code.tex 2019/04/04 v3.1.2 (3.1.2)
))
("C:\Users\Win8\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/xcolor\xcolor.sty"
Package: xcolor 2016/05/11 v2.12 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
("C:\Users\Win8\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics-cfg\color.
cfg"
File: color.cfg 2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
)
Package xcolor Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 225.
Package xcolor Info: Model `cmy' substituted by `cmy0' on input line 1348.
Package xcolor Info: Model `hsb' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1352.
Package xcolor Info: Model `RGB' extended on input line 1364.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HTML' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1366.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Hsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1367.
Package xcolor Info: Model `tHsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1368.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HSB' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1369.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Gray' substituted by `gray' on input line 1370.
Package xcolor Info: Model `wave' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1371.
)
("C:\Users\Win8\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pg
fcore.code.tex"
Package: pgfcore 2019/04/04 v3.1.2 (3.1.2)
("C:\Users\Win8\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmath.
code.tex"
("C:\Users\Win8\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathc
alc.code.tex"
("C:\Users\Win8\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathu
til.code.tex")
("C:\Users\Win8\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathp
arser.code.tex"
\pgfmath@dimen=\dimen138
\pgfmath@count=\count115
\pgfmath@box=\box36
\pgfmath@toks=\toks23
\pgfmath@stack@operand=\toks24
\pgfmath@stack@operation=\toks25
)
```

---

part1

```
LOG FILE :
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (MiKTeX 2.9.7000 64-bit) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2019.4.12) 23 AUG 2020 16:57
entering extended mode
**./introthesis.tex
(introthesis.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>
("C:\Users\Win8\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/beamer\beamer.cls"
Document Class: beamer 2018/12/02 v3.55 A class for typesetting presentations
("C:\Users\Win8\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/beamer\beamerbasemo
des.sty"
("C:\Users\Win8\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/etoolbox\etoolbox.s
ty"
Package: etoolbox 2018/08/19 v2.5f e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
\etb@tempcnta=\count80
)
\beamer@tempbox=\box27
\beamer@tempcount=\count81
\c@beamerpauses=\count82
("C:\Users\Win8\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/beamer\beamerbasede
code.sty"
\beamer@slideinframe=\count83
\beamer@minimum=\count84
)
\beamer@commentbox=\box28
\beamer@modecount=\count85
)
("C:\Users\Win8\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/oberdiek\ifpdf.st
y"
Package: ifpdf 2018/09/07 v3.3 Provides the ifpdf switch
)
\headdp=\dimen102
\footheight=\dimen103
\sidebarheight=\dimen104
\beamer@tempdim=\dimen105
\beamer@finalheight=\dimen106
\beamer@animht=\dimen107
\beamer@animdp=\dimen108
\beamer@animwd=\dimen109
\beamer@leftmargin=\dimen110
\beamer@rightmargin=\dimen111
\beamer@leftsidebar=\dimen112
\beamer@rightsidebar=\dimen113
\beamer@boxsize=\dimen114
\beamer@vboxoffset=\dimen115
\beamer@descdefault=\dimen116
\beamer@descriptionwidth=\dimen117
\beamer@lastskip=\skip41
\beamer@areabox=\box29
\beamer@animcurrent=\box30
\beamer@animshowbox=\box31
\beamer@sectionbox=\box32
\beamer@logobox=\box33
\beamer@linebox=\box34
\beamer@sectioncount=\count86
\beamer@subsubsectionmax=\count87
\beamer@subsectionmax=\count88
\beamer@sectionmax=\count89
\beamer@totalheads=\count90
\beamer@headcounter=\count91
\beamer@partstartpage=\count92
\beamer@sectionstartpage=\count93
\beamer@subsectionstartpage=\count94
\beamer@animationtempa=\count95
\beamer@animationtempb=\count96
\beamer@xpos=\count97
\beamer@ypos=\count98
\beamer@ypos@offset=\count99
\beamer@showpartnumber=\count100
\beamer@currentsubsection=\count101
\beamer@coveringdepth=\count102
\beamer@sectionadjust=\count103
\beamer@tocsectionnumber=\count104
("C:\Users\Win8\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/beamer\beamerbaseop
tions.sty"
("C:\Users\Win8\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics\keyval.sty
"
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks14
))
\beamer@paperwidth=\skip42
\beamer@paperheight=\skip43
("C:\Users\Win8\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/geometry\geometry.s
ty"
Package: geometry 2018/04/16 v5.8 Page Geometry
("C:\Users\Win8\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/oberdiek\ifvtex.s
ty"
Package: ifvtex 2016/05/16 v1.6 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
Package ifvtex Info: VTeX not detected.
)
("C:\Users\Win8\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/ifxetex\ifxetex.s
ty"
Package: ifxetex 2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
)
\Gm@cnth=\count105
\Gm@cntv=\count106
\c@Gm@tempcnt=\count107
\Gm@bindingoffset=\dimen118
\Gm@wd@mp=\dimen119
\Gm@odd@mp=\dimen120
\Gm@even@mp=\dimen121
\Gm@layoutwidth=\dimen122
\Gm@layoutheight=\dimen123
\Gm@layouthoffset=\dimen124
\Gm@layoutvoffset=\dimen125
\Gm@dimlist=\toks15
("C:\Users\Win8\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/geometry\geometry.c
fg"))
("C:\Users\Win8\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\size11.clo"
File: size11.clo 2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
("C:\Users\Win8\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer\pgfc
ore.sty"
("C:\Users\Win8\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics\graphicx.s
ty"
Package: graphicx 2017/06/01 v1.1a Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
("C:\Users\Win8\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics\graphics.s
ty"
Package: graphics 2017/06/25 v1.2c Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
("C:\Users\Win8\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics\trig.sty"
Package: trig 2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
("C:\Users\Win8\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics-cfg\graphi
cs.cfg"
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 99.
("C:\Users\Win8\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics-def\pdftex
.def"
File: pdftex.def 2018/01/08 v1.0l Graphics/color driver for pdftex
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen126
\Gin@req@width=\dimen127
)
("C:\Users\Win8\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/pgf/systemlayer\pgf
sys.sty"
("C:\Users\Win8\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/pgf/utilities\pgfrc
s.sty"
("C:\Users\Win8\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgf
util-common.tex"
\pgfutil@everybye=\toks16
\pgfutil@tempdima=\dimen128
\pgfutil@tempdimb=\dimen129
("C:\Users\Win8\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgf
util-common-lists.tex"))
("C:\Users\Win8\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgf
util-latex.def"
\pgfutil@abb=\box35
("C:\Users\Win8\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/ms\everyshi.sty"
Package: everyshi 2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
))
("C:\Users\Win8\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgf
rcs.code.tex"
("C:\Users\Win8\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf\pgf.revision.
tex")
Package: pgfrcs 2019/04/04 v3.1.2 (3.1.2)
))
("C:\Users\Win8\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer\p
gfsys.code.tex"
Package: pgfsys 2019/04/04 v3.1.2 (3.1.2)
("C:\Users\Win8\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgf
keys.code.tex"
\pgfkeys@pathtoks=\toks17
\pgfkeys@temptoks=\toks18
("C:\Users\Win8\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgf
keysfiltered.code.tex"
\pgfkeys@tmptoks=\toks19
))
\pgf@x=\dimen130
\pgf@y=\dimen131
\pgf@xa=\dimen132
\pgf@ya=\dimen133
\pgf@xb=\dimen134
\pgf@yb=\dimen135
\pgf@xc=\dimen136
\pgf@yc=\dimen137
\w@pgf@writea=\write3
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Please check the line for pdflatex: it should be  `synctex=1`. I suppose it's a typo in your post, but one never knows.

Comment: Could you copy and paste the error itself?  It will tell you what file it's not finding.

Comment: yes I wrote it as you see synctex=1,

Comment: There was not any warning or error

Comment: I try to copy LOG FILE but it was more than 30000 characters.

Comment: I post the file now in two parts as an answeer

Comment: You don't have `synctex=1`, you have `syncte=1`.  Please post the log file here, not as answers.  Please remove the packages that aren't causing the error, so that you end up with a shorter log file.  Do you still get the error with `article` instead of `beamer`?  It looks like you're missing the package `msg-msg`, which is loaded by the package `msg`, which is loaded by the package `french`.

Comment: from the beginning I used synctex=1, the change from beamer to article show no solving, I add the line; \usepackage{msg-msg}, there were no changes.

Comment: please let me know what is the mean of this line 'Package ifvtex Info: VTeX not detected."

Comment: I override the warning by cancel the line \usepackage{french}, but when I try to add others sile I face the warning I can show it in another question thank you